# Unity3d OnTriggerEnter c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am trying to get a score counter going when one object passes through an empty object. Below is the code I am using.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
     var collider = projectile.gameObject;
     score = score+1;
    // Debug.Log(collider);
    Debug.Log(score);
}
```

The score increments when the projectile passes through the object but if i shoot a second one, the score wont increment again, until the first projectile rolls back through and it goes to two.

What I would like to know is how to destroy the object after one second of passing through the empty object, increment the score by one while storing that score, also allow another object to pass through and repeat the previous steps but incrementing the score to 2 and so on.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is the OnTriggerEnter method implemented in the object or in the projectile class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The score increments when the projectile passes through the object but
>   if i shoot a second one, the score wont increment again, until the
>   first projectile rolls back through and it goes to two.

I guess that your score variable is defined in your projectile script instance, so different projectiles have different score variable instances. 
I suggest you to store you score somewhere else than the projectile's scripts.

Use a class (es.Score Manager) to store the score and add a reference to it in your projectiles scripts.

> What I would like to know is how to destroy the object after one
>   second of passing through the empty object, increment the score by one
>   while storing that score, also allow another object to pass through
>   and repeat the previous steps but incrementing the score to 2 and so
>   on.

This won't solve your problem. Btw you can destroy an object using [Object.Destroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html?from=GameObject) method:

```
GameObject aGameObject;
...
GameObject.Destroy(aGameObject); //this will destroy the object referenced by aGameObject
```

Comment: thanks i just had script added to wrong thing, thanks for the help